# Play Youtube video in MPMoviePlayerController or play RTSP - 3GP link

Tags: youtube, embed, mpmovieplayercontroller, rtsp, 3gp

I've checked on stackoverflow and searched all over the internet but haven't been able to find a solution to my problem.
In my app I need to have control over the way a youtube video is shown. I need to have control over the MPMoviePlayerController and thereby MPMediaPlayback properties. So actually I have 3 questions:

1. Is there already a solution for playing youtube videos directly in a MPMoviePlayerController that you create yourself?
2. Is it somehow possible to play the RTSP - 3GP links youtube has for the mobile site in the MPMoviePlayerController? (Right now it refuses the RTSP format)
3. Is it possible to have control over the MPMoviePlayerController that starts whenever a youtube video is embedded in a UIWebView?

If only one of these 3 questions can be answered I would be very happy!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

1. No
2. No
3. No idea - might be worth investigating by checking for NSNotifications