# Can an iPhone/iPad app embed a browser that can play RTSP stream using an HTML5 tag?

Tags: android, ios, browser

Hi I'm having some question about embedding a browser into my app. actually I want this app have both Android and iOS version. what I want to do is: the app can embed a browser (like a view in the app). and the browser should support HTML5, and it should support playing rtsp stream. when I'm trying to do this, I'm facing some problems:

1. Is there a possibility to embed a browser (like Safari or Chrome) into my app? Not by open a new window outside the app, actually I want it to be "In" the app.
2. If I can embed a browser into my app, if the browser support html5, then Can I use the browser to show rtsp stream?

if I can't embed browser, Can I embed any html5 player which support rtsp?

thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no

Yes you can embed an uiWebView that will have some functionality of a browser, you have a lot of control over what you can code.

rtsp , short answer no, IOS does not support rtsp so no html 5 tag will support rtsp

long answer, did this type of stuff several years ago.

https://github.com/mooncatventures-group/WebStreamX_flv_demo/blob/master/WebViewController.m

Here's key to how this works , this says if I click on a video link of the type defined then call the custom method to play a video otherwise process the link as a normal web link. there is other code in this git for playing rtsp feeds.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView 
shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request 
 navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{
  url = [[request URL] absoluteString];
    if([url hasSuffix:@".m4v"]==YES || [url hasSuffix:@"mp4"]==YES || [url hasSuffix:@"mov"] == YES || [url hasSuffix:@"mpg"] == YES){

    [self playMovie:url];
    return NO;
}else {

return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although you can't embed Safari or Chrome, as for 1) on Android you can use the class [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html). On iOS you can use the [UIWebView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class. For 2) there's a [related SO question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10411250/mpmovieplayercontroller-playing-youtube-video). HTH.