# Play live stream video using UIWebView is not working

Tags: ios, video, uiwebview, http-live-streaming

Hi in my Application i have `URL` of live stream video I'm trying to play the video using `UIWebView` its not working its showing empty screen.

My `URL`.

```
rtsp://v2.audiovideostream.com:1935/live/jredeems3
```

My `UIWebView` code.

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad
  {
     [super viewDidLoad];

      NSString *stream = @"rtsp://v2.audiovideostream.com:1935/live/jredeems3";

      NSURL *myURL =[NSURL URLWithString:stream];
      NSURLRequest *myRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myURL];
      [webview loadRequest:myRequest];
  }
```

I'm using the above code but its not working for me please tell is it the right way play the live stream video or where I'm doing wrong. I have been stuck here for long time please somebody help me out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

rtsp is not supported by UIWebView out of the box but there are some workarounds. Check out this question for further details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13186544/2304242